# remove trailing slash with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I want to remove file endings (.html) and the trailing slashes in urls. When the user enters the requests ttp://example.com/jobs/director.html he should be redirected to http://example.com/jobs/director. This works perfectly for most cases, but when the page name equals the name of a subdirectory the trailing slash isn't removed and the server tries to resolve the path like this: /jobs/.html (the request in this case was http://example.com/jobs/). Does anybody know a solution? I am really stuck. Thanks!

My file structure:

- jobs (directory)
- jobs/artist.html
- jobs/director.html
- index.html
- jobs.html

My .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# remove .html file ending
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: If you want `jobs.html` to be accessible via `/jobs`, then how is the server supposed to know if the HTML file or the folder was requested? This is not a good setup, and even if you’d manage to solve this single issue now, it might lead to further problems in the future. I’d strongly recommend that you change either of those two names to something different.

Comment: _“but when the page name equals the name of a subdirectory the trailing slash isn't removed”_ – pretty sure it _is_ – but then the default mechanism of redirecting directories that are requested without a trailing slash to the version with a trailing slash kicks in, and undoes your removal … the [`DirectorySlash`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) directive controls this behavior, but before you mess with it I suggest you read the documentation on it very carefully.

Comment: i can't change the structure cause i need to have the jobs subpages (jobs/artist, jobs/director). I could move the jobs.html inside the directory as index.html, but i have read that DirectoryIndex is only requested when DirectorySlash is turned on. Thanks for the links to the documentation, i am new to this topic, but it is well explained and i now understand that i have to be careful, when i turn the DirectorySlash off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off

# remove trailing slash to non-directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,L]

# add trailing slash internally to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+?[^/])$ $1/ [L]

# add .html file ending internally
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this works! I think about if this solution is bad for the performance (if it could be solved with less redirects), but i am new to this topic. After reading some documentation i think the best solution would be to solve it with DirectoryIndexes (i could move the jobs.html inside the directory jobs and rename it to index.html), but i think this is impossible, cause i turned DirectorySlash off.

Comment: thanks you are right, i didn't understood the difference between an external redirect and an internal rewrite!

Comment: For a real directory either first rule fires OR the second one since one has `!-d` condition and other has `-d` condition so there is no performance issue.

Comment: i have one problem with this solution, when a subpage is requested with a trailing slash (for example http://example.com/jobs/artist/) then to the url the internal server path is appended (http://example.at/var/www/vhosts/internal-server-path/jobs/artist)